# Append Custom ErrorCode in Mulesoft

Tags: java, exception, mule

For most of the errors in Mulesoft there is no error code defined. If it doesn't know, Mule flatly prints `MULE_ERROR--2`. Instead of this I want to put in my own error code which will be fetched from DB and include it in the exception payload. After this, the exception payload should be sent to a handler flow for re-submission based on error code. Hence in error handling part of the flow I need to have more than one component.

Tried Custom Exception Strategy, Catch Exception Strategy, Using Java component and flow-refs but none of them worked.

Also, I built a dummy code for this (without fetching the error code) to put my own custom error msg and what I noticed is, it throws the same error twice, once by default for the first time and again when I put my error msg and throw the error. To suppress  this I put

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy" level="FATAL"/>
```

in `log4j2.xml`.

Will this cause any issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your own Errors and customise it. Follow below link for further information,

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/api-dev/api-best-practices-response-handling/

Below is the content for the same :

Use HTTP Status Codes

One of the most commonly misused HTTP Status Codes is 200 – ok or the request was successful.  Surprisingly, you’ll find that a lot of APIs use 200 when creating an object (status code 201), or even when the response fails:

invalid200

In the above case, if the developer is solely relying on the status code to see if the request was successful, the program will continue on not realizing that the request failed, and that it did something wrong.  This is especially important if there are dependencies within the program on that record existing.  Instead, the correct status code to use would have been 400 to indicate a “Bad Request.”

By using the correct status codes, developers can quickly see what is happening with the application and do a “quick check” for errors without having to rely on the body’s response.

You can find a full list of status codes in the HTTP/1.1 RFC, but just for a quick reference, here are some of the most commonly used Status Codes for RESTful APIs:

200 Ok

201 Created

304 Not Modified

400 Bad Request

401 Not Authorized

403 Forbidden

404 Page/ Resource Not Found

405 Method Not Allowed

415 Unsupported Media Type

500 Internal Server Error

Of course, if you feel like being really creative, you can always take advantage of status code:
418 I’m a Teapot

It’s important to note that Twitter’s famed 420 status code – Enhance Your Calm, is not really a standardized response, and you should probably just stick to status code 429 for too many requests instead.

Use Descriptive Error Messages
Again, status codes help developers quickly identify the result of their call, allowing for quick success and failure checks.  But in the event of a failure, it’s also important to make sure the developer understands WHY the call failed.  This is especially crucial to the initial integration of your API (remember, the easier your API is to integrate, the more likely people are to use it), as well as general maintenance when bugs or other issues come up.

You’ll want your error body to be well formed, and descriptive.  This means telling the developer what happened, why it happened, and most importantly – how to fix it.  You should avoid using generic or non-descriptive error messages such as:

redx   Your request could not be completed

redx   An error occurred

redx   Invalid request

Generic error messages are one of the biggest hinderances to API integration as developers may struggle for hours trying to figure out why the call is failing, even misinterpreting the intent of the error message altogether. And eventually, if they can’t figure it out, they may stop trying altogether.

For example, I struggled for about 30 minutes with one API trying to figure out why I was getting a “This call is not allowed” error response. After repeatedly reformatting my request and trying different approaches, I finally called support (in an extremely frustrated mood) only to find out it was referring to my access token, which just so happened to be one letter off due to my inability to copy and paste such things.

Just the same, an “Invalid Access Token” response would have saved me a ton of hassle, and from feeling like a complete idiot while on the line with support.  It would have also saved them valuable time working on real bugs, instead of trying to troubleshoot the most basic of steps (btw – whenever I get an error the key and token are the first things I check now).

Here are some more examples of descriptive error messages:

greencheckmark   Your API Key is Invalid, Generate a Valid API Key at http://…

greencheckmark   A User ID is required for this action. Read more at http://…

greencheckmark   Your JSON was not properly formed. See example JSON here: http://…

But you can go even further, remember- you’ll want to tell the developer what happened, why it happened, and how to fix it.  One of the best ways to do that is by responding with a standardized error format that returns a code (for support reference), the description of what happened, and a link to the appropriate documentation so that they can learn more/ fix it:

{
  "error" : {
    "code" : "e3526",
    "message" : "Missing UserID",
    "description" : "A UserID is required to edit a user.",
    "link" : "http://docs.mysite.com/errors/e3526/"
  }
}

On a support and development side, by doing this you can also track the hits to these pages to see what areas tend to be more troublesome for your users – allowing you to provide even better documentation/ build a better API.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put a full answer here. If the link stops working, the answer is lost.

Comment: Thanks Niranjan for the answer but I believe you have specified errors for APIs using RAML. I had to design custom error codes for ALL Mulesoft errors like SFTP errors, DWL errors, any Java errors,etc. I have done it and designed a separate Mule flows for that.